# Draggable div property is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have created a draggable DIV by code-

```
<div id="Age"
     draggable="true"
     ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50px" height="25px"
     style="background-color:Green;">Age</div>
```

The DIV is working fine in Firfox, Crome, but not working in IE, Opera.
Is there any other way to create a draggable DIV that works in all browsers?
Thanks,

**EDITED**

```
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
   }</script>
```

Can anyone provede me the solution with jQuery?

Comment: may i know the IE version

Comment: I have checked in IE7, IE9 standerd.

Comment: in IE9 it will work , i don't know about IE7 if you show scipt code then i will able to suggest you something

Comment: it is also possible that You're using a very old version of jQuery and jQuery UI, consider upgrading. Also, you could combine all your jQuery code into a single document.ready block, which likely won't fix any problems, but will certainly clean up your code

Comment: please go through this link http://jsbin.com/ubabe3/3/edit

Comment: @saurav: But I want to do it without jQuery.

Comment: for me it's working fine in IE9 but not in IE7

Comment: You're asking for "the solution with jQuery" but you "want to do it without jQuery"?

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked for `jquery` solution :-
Add these two JS files in your page :-

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:-

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

JS:-

```
  $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            drag: function(event, ui) {}
        });
    });
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL4fx/2/) :-
and it is working in IE7 too.